# WebBrowser isn't showing SecurityInfo-Band when I load a Setting (very strange)

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I use the WPF WebBrowser-Control.
Now, when I load a content which contains Scripts, the control will be shown the yellow SecurityInfo-Band. Thats good.

But now a very strange behavior:
When I load a Setting (normal .NET-Setting), the WebBrowser isn't showing the SecurityBand anymore. I only load the setting and do nothing with it:

```
    public MainWindow() {
        var s = Settings.Default.Setting;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Does anybody seen this behavior before?

Here is a sample-project to show this behavior:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4701983/WpfApplication5.zip

When you run this and click on the button, the test.mht-file will be loaded and the Security-Band will be shown correct (the line where the Setting will be loaded is commented out).

When you remove the comment in MainWindow here:

```
//var s = Settings.Default.Setting;
```

the application is loading a Setting. And when you now click in the button, the Security-Band isn't shown anymore.

I hope someone can help me, how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself and want it to post here for the case, if another has the same problem in the future.

When I load the WebBrowser once at the beginning of the startup of my application (before I access a setting), it is working.